# Show notification on particular date and time using task scheduler

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new on android. I want to show notification on a particular date and time(For e.g on date 9 September 2017 on time 10:00 AM) in my app. I am using alarm manager but it does not work properly.

Please tell me the proper way.
MainActivity

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Intent inn = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AlarmActivity.class);
    PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            getBaseContext(), 0,inn, 0);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            calendar.getTimeInMillis(), displayIntent);

}
```

AlarmActivity

public class AlarmActivity extends Activity
{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_alarm);

    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(AlarmActivity.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification1 = new Notification.Builder(AlarmActivity.this)
            .setContentTitle("Notification")
            .setContentText("Get Notigication")
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(1, notification1);
}
```

Manifest
Permission

Comment: Have you tried something? Update the question with your code

Comment: it won't work on all phones as you remove app from application tray it kills tall the services to the app

Answer (score 0):

In order to trigger alarm you have to use WakefulBroadcastReceiver from where you will trigger a service that will generate notification in you activity.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
    ringtone.play();
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            AlarmService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

Then you will create a service like this.

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {


public AlarmService() {
    super("AlarmService");
}


@Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    contentId = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    String subtitle = intent.getStringExtra("subtitle");
    sendNotification(title, subtitle);
}
  public void sendNotification(String title, String subtitle) {


    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .build();

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.reminder_notification_view);
    contentView.setInt(R.id.layout, "setBackgroundColor",
            Color.WHITE);
    contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.image, R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
    contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, subtitle);
    notification.contentView = contentView;

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    notification.contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, someRandomId,
            intent, 0);

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; //Do not clear the notification
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS; // LED
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE; //Vibration
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND; // Sound

    mNotificationManager.notify(someRandomId, notification);

}
```

}

Comment: What is DLConstants?